# CASE when in where in SQL

Tags: sql

```
DECLARE @ONum int --variable
DECLARE @CrUsId nvarchar(128) = 'D901D15C-62FA-4243-A3DB-D3D448DC3F91'--assign value

DECLARE @From Datetime = 4/2/2017  --assign value
DECLARE @To Datetime  = 25/2/2017  --assign value

`declare @day nvarchar(50)`
`select * from PurchaseOrder`

where 
 CreateUserID =  CASE @CrUsId
  WHEN @CrUsId = '' THEN CreateUserID
 WHEN @CrUsId <> CreateUserID THEN NULL  -- if input is some text but      
   WHEN @CrUsId IS NULL THEN CreateUserID
  WHEN @CrUsId != '' AND CreateUserID = @CrUsId THEN CreateUserID
 END
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  Your code looks awful, but that's not a question.

Comment: This non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
select * from PurchaseOrder
    where CreateUserID =  
        CASE 
            WHEN @CrUsId = '' OR @CrUsId IS NULL THEN CreateUserID
            WHEN @CrUsId <> CreateUserID THEN NULL  -- if input is some text but      
            WHEN @CrUsId = CreateUserID THEN CreateUserID
        END
```